# Why is my Plotly (JS) ribbon chart coming out wrong?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am using Plotly in Javascript to create a ribbon plot, an example shown [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/ribbon-plots/).

My x-axis is time, which I simplified to a series of integers, one for each ribbon or nine in total.

My y-axis is a duration.

Z-axis is a weight between zero and five.

As you can see in the attached screenshot, I just can't get ribbons to show the way I expect.  I think my dataset is fine.  I'm not just presenting the data to Plotly properly?  I can't find any documentation about the data format required.  Running out of patience for guess-and-check.

Any advice SO?

A sample coordinate looks like this:

```
x: 0,1, y: 1650,1650, z: 4,4
```

There is x from zero to 9,10 or nine ribbons.  Y varies from near zero to 8,000.  Z is always 0 to 5.

I don't know why I need to declare the coordinates in pairs, which could very well be my problem.  Please advise!

[image]

Comment: This looks like the typical "data isn't sorted by x" problem in plotting, but I don't know plotly specifically. Or perhaps x and y need to be swapped?

Comment: Swapping x and y yields the same result.  I will look at the x axis data carefully.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the issue, but it seems you want to reverse the xaxis (?), in which case you can set `autorange: "reversed"` in the layout config (in the `layout.scene.xaxis` object).